# Storing multiple results from JSON

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

Can anyone suggest a way to modify JSONParser's getQuestionJSONFromUrl() method so that it stores each question as its own object in Android? Reading multiple results via PHP JSON return from a SQL table that looks like this in a browser:

```
{"category":"elections","id":"0","title":"Who will you vote for in November's Presidential election?","published":"2012-04-02","enddate":"2012-04-30","responsetype":"0"}

{"category":"elections","id":"2","title":"Question title, ladies and gents","published":"2012-04-02","enddate":"2012-04-30","responsetype":"1"}
```

Currently, the results don't even include a space between the end brace and start brace. But I could add to my php: echo "\n"; and that would give me a space between the two rows as the JSON reads out. So that's obviously two rows of filler content for now. Eventually there'll be real content in that SQL table.

I want to be able to break these rows down into objects (probably to my local SQLite db I suppose?) so that I can use them to display each as a tablerow on the screen in a fragment. I'm not too worried about the screen aspect, but getting the data to workable form is a problem. At the moment, my code only stores the first set of braces as a JSON object. Here's all the relevant code:

```
public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
}

public JSONObject getQuestions(String category) {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", question_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", category));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getQuestionJSONFromUrl(questionURL, params);
    return json;
}


public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static JSONObject[] jsonArray = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getQuestionJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
    try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.v("while", line);
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                //Log.v("err", line);
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

Can anyone suggest a way to modify JSONParser's getQuestionJSONFromUrl() method so that it stores each question as its own object in Android? I do have a local SQLite DB in which I could add a method or two to add a second table etc:

```
package library;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Getting user login status
     * return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to making the PHP script return properly encoded JSON data. I am currently still working on how to get Android to parse it out into a JSONArray: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10019165/1231943

Answer (score 1):

make `getQuestionJSONFromUrl` return string. Then use that string to create JSONObject and parse it. look at the following example.

```
        JSONObject jsonobj=new JSONObject(str);
        String category=jsonobj.getString("category");
        String title=jsonobj.getString("title");
        int id=jsonobj.getInt("id");
        String published=jsonobj.getString("published");
        String enddate=jsonobj.getString("enddate");
        int responsetype=jsonobj.getInt("responsetype");
        System.out.println(category+" "+title +" "+id +" "+published +" "+enddate +" "+responsetype);
```

Comment: This is very helpful and works as advertised - but if the method getQuestion... runs only one time, and there's 20 (arbitrary number, sometimes it will be more, sometimes it will be less) questions that get returned, how does the method need to change to accommodate 20 separate rows from SQL?

Comment: use the for loop for retrieving more than one time, like
for(int i = 0; i<Jsonarray.length(); i++);

Comment: I've spent all day working at this and I still cannot get it to work. The best I've been able to do is detect a "}{" (end/start of two JSON) and place the first part in a string and delete the second half. I'm finding that the methods I would need aren't there.

Answer (score 1):

If your response content more result then use for loop to retrieve all data, simply follow below code, hope it will works for you.

```
 JSONArray Arraylist = new JSONArray();
Arraylist=new JSONObject(output).getJSONObject("category").getJSONArray("title");

for (int i = 0; i < Arraylist.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject headObject = Arraylist.getJSONObject(i);
    String  Question_title= headObject.optString("Question title");
    String published=headObject.optString("published");
    String enddate=headObject.optString("enddate");

}
```

Comment: I can see how all of this code would work, but I have a problem. How do I get around: while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { ? That's a natural break point (a null space) between the two sets of {} {} that show up in the JSON output from the server. How can I code a way to store the current String that gets made, then redo the while loop when a null stop its before it reaches the second row of output?